# How should we classify full sequence?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, keras, lstm

I want to classify fully sequence into two categories. I searched a lot in the web but found no result for this. My prefered way is to use LSTM model from keras to classify "full" sequence of varing rows into two categories. The problem with this approach is the different shape of **X** and **y**.  This is a sample code I wrote to explain my problem.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Dense,LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential

#(no of samples, no of rows,step, feature)
feat= np.random.randint(0, 100, (150, 250, 25,10))

#(no of samples, binary_output)
target= np.random.randint(0, 2, (150, 1))

#model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(25, 10), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(10,return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
print model.summary()

for i in xrange(target.shape[0]):
    X=feat[i]
    y=target[i]
    model.fit(X,y)
```

Here I have 150 sample sequence which I want to classify into **0** or **1**. The problem is this

> ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 250 input samples and 1 target samples.

If there is no way to carry out this in deep learning methods, can you suggest any other machine learning algorithms?

EDIT

Many have asked doubts regarding this

```
#(no of samples, no of rows,step, feature)
feat= np.random.randint(0, 100, (150, 250, 25,10))
```

150 is number of samples( consider this as 150 time series data).
250 and 10 is a time series data with 250 rows and 10 columns.
`(250, 25,10)` is additon of 25 time steps that way it can be passed to keras lstm input

Comment: What backend are you using?

Comment: What do the "250, 25, 10" mean? Keras expects you to have `X as (BatchSize =150, TimeSteps, SampleSize)` and `Y as (BatchSize=150,1)`

Comment: Sorry for any confusion I have edited the question for more clarity

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you do

```
X=feat[i]
y=target[i]
```

This removes the first axis, which causes `X.shape = (250, 25, 10)` and `y.shape == (1,)`. When you call `model.fit(X, y)` keras then assumes that `X` has 250 samples, and `y` has only one sample. Which is why you get that error.

You can solve this by extracting slices of `feat` and `target`, for example by calling

```
X=feat[i:i+batch_size]
y=target[i:i+batch_size]
```

Where `batch_size` is how many samples you want to use per iteration. If you set `batch_size = 1`, you should get the behavior you intended in your code.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have edited the question and I am using tensorflow backend. I want to classify 150 time series data into two classes

Comment: I didn get your answer, I have 150 samples of both X with dimension (250,25,10) and y with dimension (1,) and X maps to y . Batch size are you talking about this `model.fit(X,y,batch_size=1)` this also gives the same error.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the lines I gave, exactly as I gave them? If you still get an error, what is it?

Comment: `batch_size=1
for i in xrange(target.shape[0]):
    X=feat[i:i+batch_size]
    y=target[i:i+batch_size]
    model.fit(X,y)` is this what you are suggesting?

Comment: Sadly it dosent work `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 250, 25, 10)` . Can you please edit the answer and share the full working code?

Comment: Shouldn't you have `input_shape = (250, 25, 10)`?

Comment: I think I was not able to convey my question properly. Consider I  have 150 time series data with 250 rows and 10 columns. I want to classify this 150 time series data into two categories